# relation between degrees of vertices and edge removal

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, combinatorics

**I'm looking for help to prove the next question:**
 given an undirected tree with n vertices with each one's degree <= 3,
**(1)** prove that there exists an edge that if we remove we'll have two trees with number of vertices in each one - maximum (2*n/3). 
**(2)** suggest a linear algorithm that finds such an edge in the above given tree

Comment: If the tree is a root with just 3 vertices as child(4 in total), does that satisfy no(1)?

Comment: @ShihabShahriar If the (2*n/3) term was rounded up, perhaps there would be no problem.

Comment: @ShihabShahriar yes, in your example removal of any edge of them would satisfy.

Comment: Hint:  pick any edge.  If it doesn't meet the criteria, then one of its adjacent edges is better.

Answer (score 0):

Choose an arbitrary root. Do a post order traversal to compute the size of each subtree. By descending from the root via children with subtrees at least as large as their siblings, find a subtree of size between (n-1)/3 inclusive and 2(n-1)/3 + 1 exclusive (the degree bound keeps the size from decreasing by more than minus one divided by two). Sever its parent edge.

Comment: Problem is, it doesn't require the first condition to be true. (I think)

Comment: @ShihabShahriar You're going to have to be more specific.